# SSL encryption error when installing SQL Server Express

Tags: ssl, sql-server-express

I am attempting to install SQL Server Express Edition (64-bit) on my Windows 10 laptop.  It is failing, apparently because of this:

`2018-06-04 14:55:20.52 spid15s     Initializing the FallBack certificate failed with error code: 1, state: 20, error number: 0.
2018-06-04 14:55:20.52 spid15s     Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate.
2018-06-04 14:55:20.52 spid15s     Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2018-06-04 14:55:20.52 spid15s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80092004, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. Cannot find object or property.`

I do not know how to resolve this; can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:**  for some reason using VPN to log into my employer's network did not allow me to install SQL Server Express.  However, from their offices and on the company intranet the problem went away.